# Dropdown button bootstrap Error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

A Seta para baixo que marca o dropdown do botão presente no navbar esta em tamanho irregular ao tamanho do button.

Veja na imagem abaixo (Botão Azul)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"><!--------- START Navbar --------->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header"><!-- START Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Meu Site</a>
            </div><!-- END Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"><!-- START Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <div class="btn-group navbar-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Bill Gates</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- END Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        </div>
    </nav><!--------- END Navbar --------->
```

Comment: Estranho, aqui funcionou corretamente: http://prntscr.com/5x0gbl OBS: Testei no Chrome e Firefox

Comment: Estranho mesmo e adicionei todos os .css e .js tanto que esta tudo funcionando 100% menos este botão.

Comment: Dever algum outro css que está causando conflito no botão. Minha sugestão é inspecionar o elemento e verificar se não tem nenhuma regra extra que causa o problema. Usa esse fiddle como exemplo e compara os atributos: http://jsfiddle.net/xcrb4kmp/

Comment: removi o arquivo de css que tinha e o problema persiste

Comment: Em que navegador você está testando? Poderia postar o código completo que você estava utilizando.

Comment: Chrome e Firefox ambos ultima versão, utilizei o css e js do bootstrap somente (removi um css externo mas o problema continuou) possui somente este navbar, no head possui as tags link e script para os arquivos bootstrap somente, utilizei este mesmo head em outras paginas e não obtive este problema (não utilizei botões com dropdown)